# ssh_vpn or sockes_proxy set gateway?

Tags: ssh, proxy, vpn, socks

I need to secure a VPN via SSH forwarding. How can I do this?

It should work like a proxy socks, but I was not able to find the gateway via socks.

Comment: This sounds like a pretty broad question.  Are you able to narrow the scope somewhat to make it easier to answer?  For example, can you describe the VPN you're trying to secure?  What kind of attacks do you want to secure it against?

Comment: The UTM firewalls are capable of checking packets inside VPNs, or sometimes VPNs are identifiable to them, but anyone with ssh does not have to (although it has permission to use it)

I'm more likely to be able to communicate with a ssh connection that I'm sure you do not have a problem with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i test in bash comment in best work

after old answer step 4 work with

```
route add -net [server] netmask 255.255.255.255 gw [real gatway client]
```

after

```
ssh -NTCf -w 0:0 [server]
ip link set tun0 up
ip addr add 192.168.123.2/32 peer 192.168.123.1 dev tun0
route add -net 192.168.123.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.123.2
route add default gw 192.168.123.1
```

run in server

```
ip link set tun0 up
ip addr add 192.168.123.1/32 peer 192.168.123.2 dev tun0
arp -sD 192.168.123.2 eth0 pub
```

if work server with gateway u need nat comment 
`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE`

Answer (score -1):

i find Approach with ssh_vpn

this link https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH_VPN

https://superuser.com/questions/202310/ssh-vpn-default-gateway-help

1. set forward in system

```
        echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward 
        or
        edite /etc/sysctl.conf
          no commet "net.ipv4.ip_forward=1"
```

2. create ssh-kegen

```
 
        ssh-keygen
        ssh-copy-id root@[des ip server]
```

4. edite /etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
        add "PermitTunnel yes"
        and 
        change "PermitRootLogin yes"
        restart ssh service
```

5.

```
        ssh -NTCf -w 0:0 [des ip server]
```

6. to host set ip in tun0 ip with

```
i
        ip link set tun0 ip
        ip addr add 10.0.0.100/32 peer 10.0.0.200 dev tun0
```

7. to server set tun0 ip

```
        ip link set tun0 up
        ip addr add 10.0.0.200/32 peer 10.0.0.100 dev tun0
```

8. set route [see des ip ] in host

```
        ip route add [des ip server]/32 via [gatway host]
```

9. set defaul route in host

```
        route add defaul gw 10.0.0.100
```

10. go to server and set ip table

```
        iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
        iptables --table nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```